# Getting lot of unwanted broadcasts on my network

Tags: arp, bandwidth, broadcast

I am pretty new in Networking (noob), while I was monitoring my network using Wireshark, and I found that there is a lot of broadcasts happening all over the network, broadcast on Local network usually  MDNS, NBNS, ARP (Gratitious), UDP[x.x.x.255], UDP[255.255.255.255].
[image]

[image]

I wonder whether these broadcast are the reason `users facing dips in bandwidth`? And How I can mitigate it? Can these broadcast be responsible for packet drops?
Also I do not understand user systems are generating ARP broadcast? Doesn't my router should do the same?

**Network Topology:**
We have a simple network consist of a *switch (Cisco)* which is between the gateway and rest of the *Access Points (Ubiquiti)* where access points are in Mesh Configuration. Rest of the users are connected an Access Point via WiFi.

Using Ethernet wire CAT-6 (between Router-Switch and Switch-Access_point),

User Count: 50

Wifi freqency: 2.4/5GHz

ISP Bandwidth: 150 MBps (Aggregated)

[image]
(Excuse my drawing skills)

**Update**
*This is latest output of broadcast I/O Graph*
[image]

Comment: How is your topology connected? What type and model of network equipment are you using?

Comment: We have several Mesh Access Points (ubiquiti) which is connected to a Switch (Cisco) which is connected to the Gateway.

Comment: Well a single switch, you could limit the broadcasts on every single port by using storm-control. `storm-control broadcast level 5.00 2.00`

Comment: Broadcasts are not normally a problem when the network isn't totally obsolete. For a start, please add a network diagram, device details and a list of identified problems to your question. It's completely normal for all nodes to ARP servers and gateways.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. *I wonder whether these broadcast are the reason users facing dips in bandwidth?* - sounds like this may be the heart of your real question. As for the images you provide, this is not substitute for being able to look at the actual packet captures but it doesn't look concerning to me (max 10-12 broadcast/multicast frames per second isn't abnormal).

Comment: @YLearn Thanks, Looking forward to be a contributing community Member.
Yes, sometimes users face high TCP latency and sometimes high DNS latency and I guess it might be these broadcast as there is not much abnormal traffic than these broadcasts (NBNS/ARP).

Comment: @YLearn I have updated it with latest I/O Graph, if you check it mostly have 30+ (broadcast) packets/second.

Comment: @Zac67 I agree it is required, but I thought because of these broadcast users might not get the required bandwidth? What if blocking/reducing the broadcast frames like "user56700" told may work, but then another question arises that will it have any ill-effects on the network?

Comment: The broadcasts by themselves are not a problem, but they may be a symptom of something else wrong . It seems like you have a lot for the size of your network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

30 broadcasts/s at 100 bytes each translates to roughly 25 kbit/s. That is not a bandwidth problem with Ethernet, not even remotely.

As Ron T. has commented, the broadcast rate is somewhat high and might indicate other problems you have. You'll need to analyze the broadcasts for common reasons.

For instance, your snapshot indicates several ARP requests for the same IP 192.168.1.143 that may be configured for some central service but might currently be offline.

Additionally, the frequent NBNS broadcasts indicate a problem with DNS. You should run a DNS server that can resolve all commonly used names (or not). Once that's working you should disable broadcast resolution on all nodes.

Also, the broadcasts may be entirely unrelated to your problems. Basic LAN troubleshooting includes:

- check cabling/L1 connectivity for unexpected link changes and high error rates
- check L2 connectivity (VLANs) for source/dest MAC presence
- check L3 connectivity (ping) for local peers and gateway(s)
- check L3 connectivity (ping, lookup) for DNS server(s)
- check L3 connectivity (ping, traceroute, service access) for additional servers

Wireless LAN/Wi-Fi complicates things quite a bit. Check cabled nodes first and makes sure everything's fine there. Then, you need to make sure that the used channel(s) are not completely overloaded and there is no radio interference from machinery nearby. For a more detailed diagnosis a thorough survey may be required.